# Newbie question: Code line ends with column name null. How to add comment at the end of this line?

Tags: sql, oracle, comments, alias

Below we have simple query.

```
select job_id, employee_id, null --comment here
from employees 
union all
select job_id, employee_id, end_date
from job_history
order by 2
```

- When I'm trying to write some comment at the end of the first line,
  comment becomes part of the column alias.
- Result of this example is column name of third column that looks like this:
  `NULL--COMMENTHERE`
- Doesn't matter if I use `--` or `/* */` before comment.

I'm curious what is the reason for this?.

Comment: can you do `null as 'empty col' --comment here` and see if that works?

Comment: I replaced null by 'empty col' but it's not working. ORA-01790 "expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression"

Comment: Since you tagged oracle, have you looked at: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/comment.htm#LNPLS01308 ? Try /* comment here */

Comment: @Martin That documentation is for PL/SQL and may be subtly different to Oracle's SQL behaviour- this is (old) 10g documentation on [comments in SQL statements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements006.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets strip the question back to the bare minimum and remove the `UNION`, the other columns and use the `DUAL` table:

```
SELECT DUMMY -- comment
FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

```
| DUMMY |
|-------|
|     X |
```

The statement is referencing a column in a table so that column's name will be used as the alias in the statement's output.

However, if we do not reference a column and use a literal:

```
SELECT NULL -- comment
FROM   DUAL;
```

This will output:

```
| NULL--COMMENT |
|---------------|
|             X |
```

and Oracle will generate the column name from the text of the SQL statement and the alias for the column in the output will be the text of the query between the `SELECT` and `FROM` keywords so the name will be `NULL -- comment` with the whitespace stripped out.

So `SELECT NULL FROM DUAL` would have a column name of `NULL`.

A slightly more complicated version with other literal values:

```
SELECT NULL --comment here
       , NULL /* other comment */,
       'LITERAL' -- third comment
       , 0 /* fourth comment */
FROM   DUAL
```

None of the generated columns reference a named column of a table so Oracle will generate the name from the SQL and outputs:

```
| NULL--COMMENTHERE | NULL/*OTHERCOMMENT*/ | 'LITERAL'--THIRDCOMMENT | 0/*FOURTHCOMMENT*/ |
|-------------------|----------------------|-------------------------|--------------------|
|            (null) |               (null) |                 LITERAL |                  0 |
```

and you can see the column names are generated from the SQL statement select clause list delimited by commas.

The SQL statement with a `UNION` will take the column names from the first `SELECT` clause (before the `UNION`) so:

```
SELECT NULL -- comment
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT DUMMY
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

```
| NULL--COMMENT |
|---------------|
|        (null) |
|             X |
```

The column name will be from the first statement and not from the second (below the `UNION`) which does reference a column.

If you want to override the default column name then use an alias:

```
SELECT NULL "NULL" --comment here
       , NULL AS other /* other comment */,
       'LITERAL' AS literal -- third comment
       , 0 AS "0" /* fourth comment */
FROM   DUAL
```

Outputs:

```
| NULL   | other  | LITERAL | 0 |
|--------|--------|---------|---|
| (null) | (null) | LITERAL | 0 |
```

and the aliases are used and the comments have been ignored.

Comment: For me, this answer is enough. By the way I would like to thank to @MT0 for in-depth answer and tags correction, to a_horse_with_no_name for my post edition and to Martin for links as well as for interesting conversation with gentelmens mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

One issue I encountered with Oracle, is that if you put a comment before stating *FROM table*, it breaks the syntax and throws an error *"Expecting FROM keyword"*. So I would suggest you moved the comment to be *after* your *FROM table* statement, or use the `/* comment */`, or add a multi-line comment at some point, giving a more in-depth explanation instead of adding the comment directly to the select statement.

```
select job_id, employee_id, null --comment here
from employees 
union all
select job_id, employee_id, end_date
from job_history
order by 2
```

The above code is from your question, and breaks the Oracle syntax.

```
select job_id, employee_id, null from employees -- comment here
union all
select job_id, employee_id, end_date
from job_history
order by 2
```

This works.

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7dd91d/19

And since you tagged oracle,

source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/comment.htm#LNPLS01308

Comment: Martin - Thank You for link and answer. I've checked this solution several times and unfortunately is not working and "--comment here" is still added to null as the column name.

Comment: Your SQL Fiddle has the wrong database - it is using MySQL and not Oracle.

Comment: My bad @MT0, I am trying to change it, but sqlfiddle won't allow me >.<

Comment: @JZal instead of .... --comment, try ... -- comment. The space matters, as I pointed out very specifically in my answer.

Comment: The inclusion or lack of a space does not matter.

Comment: @MT0 it did when I fired an SQL command in my own database doing --comment instead of -- comment. It interpreted non space example as a part of the column alias, throwing a cloumn not found error due to it.

Comment: Various different whitespace and comment styles in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/585) and the whitespace does not affect the inclusion of the comment in the generation of the implicit alias.

Comment: @martin: The whitespace certainly does not matter to Oracle for the _correctness_ of the query

Comment: Added a working sql fiddle with the correct database now.

Comment: You've put the comment in the wrong place - it should be after the `NULL` literal and not after the table name [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7dd91d/20)

Comment: @MT0 I encountered an error, where Oracle expects the "FROM" keyword upon adding a comment *before* stating "FROM table". So I'm unsure if Oracle allows that syntax. It doesn't seem like the case, at least on sqlfiddle. Also, it's a pain doing stuff on sqlfiddle atm, it's so slow. >.<

Comment: See the fiddle in my previous comment - Oracle does allow the comment before the `FROM` clause but a `--` comment is terminated by a new line character so you must put the succeeding part of the statement (i.e. the `FROM` clause) on a new line. You can have an inline `/**/` comment on the same line as it has its own terminator characters.

Comment: @Martin: regarding SQLFiddle: I have long stopped using it because it's extremely unreliable. For Oracle I usually use [DBFiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk)  for Postgres I use [this](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oracle also provides [livesql.oracle.com](https://livesql.oracle.com) (but you do have to create an account).

Comment: Thanks MT0 and a_horse_with_no_name. I think we should keep the comments clean for now, as it is starting to look more like a "conversation" now, which should be taken to private messages. :p Appreciate the inputs a lot.